# String Manipulation: finding first occurence of pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have some text that ends with a `[br]` tag, optionally followed by more `[br]` tags and/or whitespace characters, but nothing else.  For example:

```
bla blah d [br] fkjd fkdh fkd fks
sdkf skdfh djfh[br]
[br]
[br]
```

I would like to insert text before that `[br]` tag, like this:

```
bla blah d [br] fkjd fkdh fkd fks
sdkf skdfh djfh [INSERTED TEXT][br]
[br]
[br]
```

My problem is, I don't know how many additional `[br]` tags or whitespace characters there will be.

Is there an easy way to do this in PHP?

Comment: Do you care about preserving the newlines?

Comment: your example and your text don't line up. Your question reads "would like to insert text before the first [br]" but the sample answer has the [INSERTED TEXT] before the second br?

Comment: @preinheimer My guess is he wants to insert the text on the first line *ending* in a [br].

Comment: no only the last part of the text which ends with random BR + random whitespace. thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something with [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace)?

```
preg_replace('!\[br\](\s+\[br\])+!i', 'INSERT$0', $subject);
```

The regex is looking for a `[br]` tag, followed optionally by some amount of whitespace, and further `[br]` tags. There can be any number of following `[br]` tags. The i at the end indicates case insensitivity.

You can view this running on [codepad](http://codepad.org/SnaRQhH5)

Comment: problem is there could be [BR] in the middle of the text also. thanks

Comment: Ray, i believe this one is only matching if its followed by more BR's

Comment: added example showing it being used where the [br]'s are not the last thing

Comment: thanks. the last part has only random br and random whitespace. is there a way to test ahead for this condition with preg_replace.

Comment: @RayS. The sample code I've linked works on your example, I'm not sure what you're asking for. http://codepad.org/K3VplEf5

Comment: I think you need to anchor it to the end of the string, like [Ali Shah Ahmed did](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14590498/20938).

Comment: Also, the way I read the question, everything after the target `[br]` tag is optional.  Your regex requires that there be at least one whitespace character and at least one more tag.  And you aren't accounting for possible whitespace after the final tag.  I would change `+` to `*` in both places and add `\s*$` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Basically, you would want to do something like this:

```
$str = 'bla blah dfkjd fkdh fkd fks sdkf skdfh djfh[br] [BR] [BR]';

$textToFind = '[br]';

$textToInsert = 'Hello World!';

// find the first $textToFind, ie '[br]';
$pos = strpos($str, $textToFind);

// cut from 0 to $pos, then insert the text, then $pos to the end of the string
$newStr = substr($str, 0, $pos) . $textToInsert . substr($str, $pos);

echo $newStr;
```

Comment: problem is there could be [BR] in the middle of the text also. thanks

Comment: @RayS. Well, if the `[br]` you want to find is always followed by a new line, you could just search for `[br]\n`.

Comment: thank you. but want to find the tail of the text which ends off with only random number of br + white space

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not a guy of php, but know some javescript. It might help you get some idea how to solve your problem.

```
str = str.replace(/(.*?)((<br>)*)$/,'$1' + insertedText + '$2')
```

Here `str` is the string that contains your text.
First parameter of the replace function `/(.*?)((<br>)*)$/` is the regex that matches the pattern.
`(.*?)` matches the text that appears before `<br>` tags. `((<br>)*)$` matches any number of `<br>` and makes sure that these `<br>` appear at the end of text.

Second parameter is the actual replaced string. `insertedText` is the text that you want to insert in the original string.

Hope it helps. If you need any clarification, please do not hesitate to comment.